# Is this data table normalization right?

Tags: sql, database, normalization, database-normalization

Every assignment for the database class has been reaaally long, then all of the sudden one of the assignments is what I uploaded in the picture.....is my answer correct? Is there anything left?

(my answer is the third column, below the blue text)

[image]

Comment: Hello there. Welcome to SO, please don't add imagens from links on questions (at least not this kind) this links are temporary and will eventually die and your question will be useless. Please transcribe that image here, someone will edit and format to you until you learn how to.

Comment: It says that you need to give appropriate table names but it seems that you use the primary key as table name which should not be. Also you need to be clear on the FK (Foreign Key) on how it relate to what table which was not indicated in your solution. I don't know though what's your convention in showing such.

Comment: I don't see a reference to Contaminant from any other relation.

Comment: You missed a relation corresponding to the original primary key.